# Evaluating postfix expression on multidigit numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, object-oriented, stack

This is my solution for evaluating postfix expression using a stack. It does work on multidigit numbers, the problem I was struggling with last time. Now it works completely fine.

This is the stack that I'm using:

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []
    
    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.items == []
    
    def push(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)
    
    def pop(self):
        self.items.pop()
    
    def peek(self):
        try:
            return self.items[-1]
        except:
            return False
    
    def value_at_index(self, value):
        try:
            return self.items[value]
        except:
            return False
    
    def all_items(self):
        return self.items
```

And here is my code:

```
def result(data):
    """Evaluating postfix expression"""
    stack = Stack()
    if data != False:
        for element in data:
            try:
                if type(float(element)) == float:
                    stack.push(element)
            except:
                method = "float(stack.value_at_index(-2))" + element + "float(stack.value_at_index(-1))"
                method = eval(method)
                stack.pop()
                stack.pop()
                stack.push(method)
        return stack.peek()
    else:
        return "Check your formula"

data = ['20', '10', '+', '75', '45', '-', '*']
print(result(data))
```

Output:

```
900.00
```

It works perfectly fine, but to be completely honest i would like to get rid of `eval` because of the negative opinions on this built-in function I heard. I want some reviews from you guys and advices how to generally improve it.

Using Python 3.6.7.

Comment: isn't `index_of_element` actually `value_at_index`?

Comment: @hjpotter92 well probably yeah, my bad at naming.

Comment: I'm curious: For what value of `element` have you observed `type(float(element)) == float` to be false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Python's lists are stacks.
  Your `Stack` class is making your code harder to read because it's not using Python's idioms.
- Don't use bare excepts, as all exceptions are silenced.
  You shouldn't be silencing [`SystemExit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#SystemExit) or [`KeyboardInterrupt`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#KeyboardInterrupt). Only handle the exceptions you need to handle.
- `type(float(element)) == float`
  You should default to using `isinstance`.
  You'll be building a habit of supporting child types, rather than fighting bad habits later.
- I'd suggest splitting normalizing your tokens away from evaluating the tokens.
  Basically move `float(element)` out of the function.
- We can then change your type check to check if the number is a `numbers.Number`.
- I'd recommend preferring storing numbers as `int`s rather than `float`s to avoid floating point issues.

```py
import numbers
from typing import Union, Iterable, Iterator

AToken = Union[str, numbers.Number]


def to_numbers(tokens: Iterable[str]) -> Iterator[AToken]:
    for token in tokens:
        for cast in (int, float, complex):
            try:
                yield cast(token)
                break
            except ValueError:
                pass
        else:
            yield token


def evaluate(data: Iterable[AToken]) -> numbers.Number:
    stack: list[numbers.Number] = []
    for token in data:
        if isinstance(token, numbers.Number):
            stack.append(token)
        else:
            rhs = stack.pop()
            lhs = stack.pop()
            stack.append(eval(f"{lhs}{token}{rhs}"))
    return stack[0]


data = ['20', '10', '+', '75', '45', '-', '*']
print(evaluate(to_numbers(data)))
```

We can remove the need for using `eval` by calling the appropriate dunder method.

```py
>>> getattr(1, "__add__")(2)
3
```

So we can just pass in a dictionary of {op: dunder}.

```py
def evaluate(data: Iterable[AToken], ops: dict[str, str]) -> numbers.Number:
    stack: list[numbers.Number] = []
    for token in data:
        if isinstance(token, numbers.Number):
            stack.append(token)
        else:
            rhs = stack.pop()
            lhs = stack.pop()
            stack.append(getattr(lhs, ops[token])(rhs))
    return stack[0]


OPS = {
    "+": "__add__",
    "-": "__sub__",
    "*": "__mul__",
}

data = ['20', '10', '+', '75', '45', '-', '*']
print(evaluate(to_numbers(data), OPS))
```

Comment: Now if im trying use the second part of your code without eval, im getting TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @KermitTheFrog You're probably not on Python 3.9+. Put `from __future__ import annotations` at the top of the file and the issues will disappear. Alternately change `dict[str, str]` to `"dict[str, str]"` and `list[numbers.Number]` to `"list[numbers.Number]"`.

Comment: Gotcha, i have one more question, how would it be possible to have input f.e not as splitted strings but a one input: ['20 10 + 75 45 - *']

Comment: i meant ('20 10 + 75 45 - *')

Comment: @KermitTheFrog you've probably used a poor example because you can just `'20 10 + 75 45 - *'.split()`. There are two ways you can parse the string otherwise; build a tokenizer or use *BNF (EBNF and ABNF are far nicer than BNF). You can build a parser quite easily by 1. `if char in "0123456789": token.append(char)` `else: yield "".join(token); if char in "+-*": yield char`.

Comment: @KermitTheFrog I've written up [a more in depth explanation around tokenizers explaining BNF too](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/271046). You and your classmate may be interested.